# How to remove tab feature for PrimeNG editor

Tags: angular, primeng, quill

PrimeNG's rich text editor uses quill and setting that up through JavaScript has the function to disable tabbing using this code:

```
keyboard: {
    bindings: {
        tab: false,
        handleEnter: {
            key: 13,
            handler: function() {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can reach the editor in Angular using:

```
private quill:any;

@ViewChild(Editor) editorComponent: Editor;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.quill = this.editorComponent.quill;
}
```

But how do I use the this.quill object to set tab to false? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like in Primeng we don't have any convenient way to achieve this. It could be there but I didn't find anything. So here I my solution for this. It may not be the best solution but It should solve your purpose.

**component.html**

```
<p-editor [style]="{'height':'320px'}" (onInit)="editorcall($event)"></p-editor>
```

I am using (onInit) so that we can disable the tab, as soon as editor get loaded into the DOM.

**component.ts**

```
export class EditorComponent {
     public tab = { 
          key:9,
          handler: function() {
              return false;
          }
    };
    editorcall(event:any){
        event.editor.keyboard.bindings[9].length = 0;
        event.editor.keyboard.bindings[9].push(this.tab);
      }
}
```

I just removed all the references with the Key code 9. Which is Tab key. 
Why I created a new tab object and Pushed it again in bindings, just because whenever you click on tab, mouse pointer should not go any other HTML component. It should be there inside editor only.
You can comment this line `//event.editor.keyboard.bindings[9].push(this.tab);`
and see the side effect.

Make sure this will not break your app at any place.

Comment: This was awesome! We did usability tests and the problem was that those with screen readers got stuck inside our quill text editor. So I commented the line you mentioned and voilá! You sir, saved my day!

How could I have found the .keyboard.bindings etc? Did you find it in the documentation or through angular tslint?

Comment: @TuxedoJoe I didn't find these in Primeng documentation and in quill documentation I didn't dig deeper. Your question was the key to find the solution. I thought if we remove all Tab handler and pass our own function which will return false. And I am glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add tab key handler when you create Quill editor currently this not available ,current implemention for p-editor dons't pass any custome configration for quill editor

[p-editor](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/editor/editor.ts)

```
this.quill = new Quill(editorElement, {
  modules: {
      toolbar: toolbarElement
  },
  placeholder: this.placeholder,
  readOnly: this.readonly,
  theme: 'snow',
  formats: this.formats
});
```

I only found this solution for prevent tab key

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.quill = this.editorComponent.quill;
    if (this.quill) {

     this.quill.keyboard.bindings[9].unshift({
        key: 9,
        handler: function (range) {
          console.log('tab is disabled');
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-53703313)

[key-bindings](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/keyboard/#key-bindings)